# Converting R split() function to C++

Tags: c++, r, split, rcpp

Consider the reproducible example in R:

```
test <- c(1:12)
> test
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

The expected result:

```
test.list <- split(test, gl(2, 3))
> test.list
$`1`
[1] 1 2 3 7 8 9

$`2`
[1]  4  5  6 10 11 12
```

I am trying to write equivalent code in C++ to produce and return the two vectors that resulted from the test.list. Note that, I am in the embarrassing novice stage in C++.

Comment: what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please show a [mre]

Comment: I am literally trying to understand a similar code chunk in C++ I found (https://www.techiedelight.com/split-vector-into-subvectors-cpp/) and trying to figure out if I can upgrade it to accommodate my requirement. Other than that, I do not have a reproducible example with C++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the nice answer by @jignatius and make it an R-callable function.  For simplicity I keep it at `NumericVector`; we have a boatload of answers here that show show to switch between `NumericVector` and `IntegerVector` based on the run-time payload.

#### Code

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List mysplit(Rcpp::NumericVector nums, int n, int size) {
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> result(n);
    int i = 0;
    auto beg = nums.cbegin();
    auto end = nums.cend();

    while (beg != nums.cend()) {
        //get end iterator safely
        auto next = std::distance(beg, end) >= size ? beg + size : end;
        //insert into result
        result[i].insert(result[i].end(), beg, next);
        //advance iterator
        beg = next;
        i = (i + 1) % n;
    }

    Rcpp::List ll;
    for (const auto&v : result)
        ll.push_back(v);

    return ll;
}

/*** R
testvec <- 1:12
mysplit(testvec, 2, 3)
*/
```

#### Output

```
> Rcpp::sourceCpp("~/git/stackoverflow/68858728/answer.cpp")

> testvec <- 1:12

> mysplit(testvec, 2, 3)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 7 8 9

[[2]]
[1]  4  5  6 10 11 12

>
```

There is a minor error in the original question in that we do not need a call to `gl()`; just the two scalars are needed.

Comment: Apparently you're the author of Rcpp, which enables one to use C++ in R. Very useful.

Comment: I am part of the team behind Rcpp, yes.  And indeed, it has its uses.  More [here on GitHub](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp) and _e.g._ [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rcpp/info).

Answer (score 5):

Try this, which creates a vector of vectors containing the elements from the source in alternating chunks:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
std::vector<std::vector<T>> split(std::vector<T> nums, int n, int size)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> result(n);
    int i = 0;
    auto beg = nums.cbegin();
    auto end = nums.cend();

    while (beg != nums.cend()) {
        //get end iterator safely
        auto next = std::distance(beg, end) >= size ? beg + size : end;
        //insert into result
        result[i].insert(result[i].end(), beg, next);
        //advance iterator
        beg = next;
        i = (i + 1) % n;
    }

    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vnums = { 1, 2, 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12 };
    auto vectors = split(vnums, 2, 3);

    for (const auto& v : vectors)
    {
        for (auto num : v) {
            std::cout << num << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/MqY4135x6)

Comment: Nice, though not useable from R.  I'll add that in a variant with credit to you.

Comment: Thanks for both of the solutions but special thanks for providing a solution that is usable from R which I needed exactly.